# Embeding flash files using PHP

Tags: php, html, flash

How can I link flash files using dreamweaver with the use of PHP code?

Comment: Can you explain a little more? Seriously we are not mind-readers?

Comment: you want to link as the user can download or to show the flash movie itself?

Answer (score 1):

PHP code has nothing to do with Flash...

Flash files are embed in HTML code, and if you Google for **embed flash files** I'm sure you will find plenty information regarding what you want.

Best way though is using **[SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/)**

see this [Adobe Tutorial](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/swfobject.html) or search for **SWFObject tutorial** over the net